# Iterate through several ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i had a set of `ng-model` elements and and want to sum all the values and display it. My set looks like these

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="SumApp" >
    <input ng-model='val1' type='number' ng-change='calculate()' ng-init='val1=0'/>
    <input ng-model='val2' type='number' ng-change='calculate()' ng-init='val2=0'/> 
    <input ng-model='val3' type='number' ng-change='calculate()' ng-init='val3=0'/>
    <input ng-model='val4' type='number' ng-change='calculate()' ng-init='val4=0'/>
    <div>{{sum}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my controller looks like these

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SumApp($scope) {
  $scope.sum = 0;

  $scope.calculate = function() {
     $scope.sum = $scope.val1+$scope.val2+$scope.val3+$scope.val4
  };
}
</script>
```

So like the **html** for the `models` is **generate dynamically**

The question is if there is any way that can i iterate through a set of elements `ng-model`  **without using any `list` in the controller definition itself** ?

Comment: Do you know how many of them there are?

Comment: yes i can anticipate how many are

Comment: Then why not `for(i = 0; i < howMany; i++) { sum += $scope['val' + i]; }` ?

Comment: can u answer to mark it as valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing the exact number of inputs at any time you can easily use a loop to sum them up:

```
$scope.sum = 0;
$scope.numInputs = 5;

$scope.calculate = function() {
    var i;
    $scope.sum = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < $scope.numInputs; i++) {
        $scope.sum += parseInt($scope['val' + i], 10);
    }
};
```